# SFML, Blank texture loaded onto a Sprite

Tags: c++, scope, textures, sprite, sfml

I am pretty new to SFML. So I was learning how to load a texture onto a Sprite and it seems like I can't get it right. All that loads is a white square and it gives no error message. Here is the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
   public:
     Game();
     void run();
   private:
      void processevents(), update(), render();
      void HPI(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed);
   private:
      bool IMU, IMD, IMR, IML; 
      sf::RenderWindow MW;
      sf::Sprite O; 
};

Game::Game() :MW(sf::VideoMode(1200, 650), "Dominus"), O() {
    sf::Texture PTexture;
    if (!PTexture.loadFromFile("Fridgus.png")) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not load image.png");
    }
    O.setTexture(PTexture);
    O.setPosition(400.f, 250.f);
}
void Game::run() {
    while (MW.isOpen()) {
        processevents();
        update();
        render();
    }
}
void Game::render() {
    MW.clear();
    MW.draw(O);
    MW.display();
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

I have even specified to throw in an error if the image doesn't load but it seems the image does load. I think I have a little idea about whats going on and that is it has something to do with scope but I don't understand how.
(Ignore the other functions which I haven't initialized)

Comment: Look at *The white square problem* chapter from [official SFML tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but store PTexture within the game class. I hope that fixes the bug.